# Store Unix timestamp without datetime conversion in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I would like to store unixtime stamp sent from my iot device to database. since i don't want to store it using date time conversion. i just want to add it raw so that i can show it to frontend. so which data type should i supposed to use ? because int will be the short one and big int will be the very big one and varchar will cause me performance issue thank you

Comment: http://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: Why would you want to "show [the epoch] to frontend"?

Comment: Client requirements what can programmer possibly do 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix timestamp is just bigint. Store it as bigint.